# I try to use vlookup by using vba code but it doesn't work

Tags: excel, vba

I try to use vlookup by using vba code below but it doesn't work. I want to find MMonth. How can I find my error?

```
Sub abc()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim PCFilePath As String
Dim PCFile As String
Dim RSFilePath As String
Dim RSFile As String
Dim Month As String
Dim MMonth As String
Dim Range As Range
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

PCFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")
PCFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3")
RSFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8")
RSFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9")
Month = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5")

Workbooks.Open (PCFilePath & PCFile), UpdateLinks:=0
Set x = Workbooks.Open(PCFilePath & PCFile)

Workbooks.Open (RSFilePath & RSFile), UpdateLinks:=0
Set y = Workbooks.Open(RSFilePath & RSFile)

Set WB = ThisWorkbook

'Vlookup the date
Set Range = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:E")
MMonth = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Month, Range, 4, True)

End Sub
```

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful description of what happens when you run your code.  Please update your question to describe exactly what's going wrong.

Comment: I would like to use the value "month" which is at the one of the cell of first column of the range B:E at "Range", to find a value "MMonth" which is at the same row with "month" but fourth column of the range B:E at "Range". The error is "1004"

Comment: *On which line* is the error, and what's the error text?

Comment: "MMonth = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Month, Range, 4, True)" The error now is run time error '5' Invalid procedure call or argument

Comment: `Month` and `Range` are reserved names in VBA. `Month` is an VBA Function and `Range` is an object, so I strongly suggest you to avoid those words as variables.

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

- Opening a workbook and setting it to variable. Only one should be done.
- Never use variable names that are also functions, like `Month` & `Range`
- Use `Range.Find` for Searching

**Here:**

```
Sub abc()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim PCFilePath As String
Dim PCFile As String
Dim RSFilePath As String
Dim RSFile As String
Dim mth As String
Dim MMonth As String
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Date1 As Date
Dim Date2 As Date

PCFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
PCFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Value
RSFilePath = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B8").Value
RSFile = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B9").Value
mth = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B5").Value

'Workbooks.Open (PCFilePath & PCFile), UpdateLinks:=0
Set x = Workbooks.Open(PCFilePath & PCFile)

'Workbooks.Open (RSFilePath & RSFile), UpdateLinks:=0
Set y = Workbooks.Open(RSFilePath & RSFile)

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
Dim fnd As Range
'Vlookup the date
Set Rng = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:E")
Set fnd = Rng.Find(mth)

If Not fnd Is Nothing Then

    MMonth = fnd.Value
    MsgBox "Value Found " & MMonth
End If



End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 


I would like to use the value "month" which is at the one of the cell of first column of the range B:E at "Range", to find a value "MMonth" which is at the same row with "month" but fourth column of the range B:E at "Range". The error is "1004". Your working still show me the value of "month"

Answer (score 0):

A few fixes:

```
Sub abc()

    Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim PCFilePath As String
    Dim RSFilePath As String
    Dim sMonth As String
    Dim MMonth As Variant '<< not string
    Dim rngSearch As Range

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
        PCFilePath = .Range("B2").Value & .Range("B3").Value
        RSFilePath = .Range("B8").Value & .Range("B9").Value
        sMonth = .Range("B5").Value
    End With

    Set x = Workbooks.Open(PCFilePath, UpdateLinks:=0)
    Set y = Workbooks.Open(RSFilePath, UpdateLinks:=0)        
    Set WB = ThisWorkbook 'what's this for?

    Set rngSearch = y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B:E")

    'Drop the WorksheetFunction so it doesn't raise a
    '  run-time error of there's no match
    MMonth = Application.VLookup(sMonth, rngSearch, 4, True)
    If Not IsError(MMonth) then
        Debug.Print "Got " & MMonth
    Else
        Debug.Print sMonth & " was not found!"
    End If

End Sub
```